# How to get the (x,y,z) coordinates of a 3D model of every click in Python?

Tags: python, 3d, blender, mayavi

The input to the program is an `obj` file of the form

```
# write_obj (c) 
g
# object curobj to come
# 23372 vertex
v -63.022500 20.254900 -28.502400
v -63.022500 19.742100 -28.437200
...
...
vt -1.000000 -1.000000
vt -1.000000 -1.000000
...
...
f 5131/5131 5132/5132 5271/5271
f 5130/5130 5270/5270 5269/5269
...
...
```

This would generate a 3D model in applications like Blender and Mayavi. Although these frameworks can render these images, there is no simple way to get the 3D coordinates on mouse click event.

Is there a simple program in Mayavi (or Blender) to get the (x,y,z) coordinates of the point/vertex on which the mouse is clicked?

Answer (score -1):

Most popular modeling aps for python have useful functions for doing just this! I suggest reading through their [API's](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/) to better understand some of their capabilities.

For blender, something like:

```
obj = Blender.Object.GetSelected()
coords = obj.location
```

should return a vector with the 3 co-ordinates you are looking for. Sorry I am not familiar with Mayavi but im sure there should be a similar command. Hope this helps